# Printing longer than calculated Average words in C program

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have a program that currently reads in words to a variable *char wordlist[lengthOfArray]; So basically it holds char word[10]. I can calculate average word lengths successfully, but I have a method that I want to print the words longer than this average recursively

```
void printAverage(char *wordlist, int n, int average){
 if (n > 0){
    if (strlen(wordlist[0]) > average){
       printf("%s\n", wordlist[0]);   // Print the one longer than average then move on
       printAverage(wordlist + 1, n-1, average);
      }
      else { 
           printAverage(wordlist+1, n-1, average);
           }
    }
 }
```

I have looked for hours online to see what is wrong, but for some reason, the comparison
if (strlen(a[0]) > average) isn't getting the value of my word correctly, and giving me the error
passing arg 1 of strlen makes pointer from Integer without a cast.

Does anyone have any idea how exactly I can do this correctly? Thanks in advance for any help, I am just stuck and I have already tried many things to no avail.

Comment: Where is "a" declared?

Comment: ah sorry, a is actually wordlist

Comment: Are the word strings normally nul terminated? How exactly does the function fail? Does it print all words or none at all? There are no obvious problems in it...

Comment: It doesn't do anything, and sometimes crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring wordlist as a pointer to char instead of pointer to pointer to char.
char is an integral type so when you dereference it as wordlist[0] and pass it to strlen() the compiler warns you about passing an integral type instead of a pointer.

Try:

```
void printAverage(char **wordlist, int n, int average)
{
  if (n > 0){
    if (strlen(wordlist[0]) > average){
      printf("%s\n", wordlist[0]);   // Print the one longer than average then move on
    }
    printAverage(wordlist + 1, n-1, average);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just gave it a spin, sadly it says [Warning] passing arg 1 of `printAverage' from incompatible pointer type. I am learning from what you are saying though :)

Comment: @KadinBoyle Which call of printAverage did it say that for?

Comment: @JimBalter Just the method as it is before its even called

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `wordlist` is not an array of words - it is a string.  If you have an array of words it's either a 2D array like this:

```
char *wordlist[]
```

Or this:

```
char wordlist[][10]
```

Or a double-pointer like this:

```
char **wordlist
```

You need to set up the parameter according to the actual data you are passing into it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, but I have declared wordlist as you said char *wordlist[].   Do I also need to pass it in as *wordlist[]?

Comment: @KadinBoyle It's an odd question. Of course the types must match. And you are doing strlen and printf("%s") on wordlist[0], so of course it must be a `char*`, and wordlist itself must be a pointer to a `char*` (declaring it as `char* wordlist[]` is the same as declaring it as `char** wordlist`). The argument passed is just `wordlist`.

Comment: @KadinBoyle If your `wordlist` outside the function is declared as `char *wordlist[10]`, then you pass it simply as `wordlist` when you call the function.